# How to dynamically change the road capacity of a road

Tags: anylogic

I drew a  road network, which needs to dynamically change the capacity of a road in the process of model operation. For example, the capacity of a road in the first minute is 1000 v/h, and that in the second minute is 500 v/h.

Comment: what do you mean by capacity? the number of vehicles that arrive per hour? or the amount of vehicles that fit in the road? Why would the capacity of a road change?

Comment: Road capactity is defined implicitly in the Road Traffic Library (lanes, length, distance of cars), explicitely in path networks for AGVs (eg. max. 10 AGV for one path element at a given time) and not at all for a normal path network. Throughput cannot be explicitely be defined by that means. Maybe a more abstract approach can do this, such as using service processes or System Dynamics.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please forgive me for being a novice technician. What I want to do is that the traffic was running normally some time ago. Suddenly, an accident happened on a road and the traffic capacity was reduced. But I don't know how AnyLogic can simulate this situation.

Answer (score 4):

This solution doesn't use stop lines and can make the accident occur anywhere you want at random moments.
[image: model structure]

First in the source I am adding the car population to the cars population (remember to make your population to start EMPTY... the default is 100, you have to change the default):
[image: car source]

You have a normal carMoveTo and with an event, or a button or whatever you want, you can define the accident by changing the speed of the car to zero... So in the event after 15 seconds, I created the accident like this:

```
Car car=cars.random(); //I choose a random car to be accidented
car.setPreferredSpeed(0,KPH); //speed to 0 kph making it stop
create_MyDynamicEvent(30,SECOND,car); //this will fix the accident in 30 seconds
```

The dynamic event has the following code:
[image]

Comment: Definitely more flexible, nice solution!

Comment: it really helped me ,Thank you so much(^-^)

Answer (score 1):

You could model the situation like this:

[image: Process Flows]

Creating a car in a separate Source and process flow (the lower one), where the target of the carMoveTo block is not the real target, but rather the position where it will "break down", here at the marked stopLine, where you can see the stopped red car. Other cars will now automatically go around the obstacle, some will have to move lane. This will implicitly decrease your throughput.

In this example, the breakDown (delay) block defines how long the car is broken/blocking the road, afterwards it is again released and will leave the road like all others.

Comment: Tnank you for your reply so much ,Florian(^-^)